# how to rename a multiple file name from a folder without changing a file extension

Tags: python

[image: This image is my code.]

Please guide how to rename all the files in the folder without changing their extension. In this I have tried for one format(.wav)

Comment: what's with the `p=hei)`?  The parentheses looks like a typo.

Comment: Your 2nd `for` loop should be deleted - it will ignore the `if *.wav` statement, since it's operating on `files`, the original list of files.

Answer (score 0):

Try `os.path.splitext()`, which returns the start of the filename, and the file extension as the first and second elements of a tuple.

Example:

```
import os
f = "mymusic.wav"
filename,ext = os.path.splitext(f)    # save the file extension
    # filename = "mymusic"; ext = ".wav"
filename = filename + "_new"
os.rename(f, filename+ext)    # generate new filename with same extension
```

Comment: i need to rename multiple formats.this is rename code for only one format.Please guide me for multiple file formats to rename.

Comment: Whatever the 'format' (file extension), this code saves the extension and sticks it back on the end of the new file.  Would work for `mymusic.mp3`, `mymusic.mp3456789` or whatever.

Comment: Sorry.Can you please help for multiple files rename at a time using python without changing the extension.Don't need to specify the file extension.any file in the folder i need to rename.

Comment: I'm suspicious that this is a homework problem, as you don't seem to have much input on the subject, nor be trying very much, just looking for someone else to solve it for you.